# fill the interior of a randomly constructed closed path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, random-numbers

I am not sure how to proceed in filling the interior of a randomly generated (via a random decoration) path.

I began with code given in the answer to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35534/tips-for-creating-semi-random-blob-in-tikz) and worked on it since the basic purpose was related.

[image: imageyes]

The fill and the drawn line are not quite the same, because there is a random decoration applied to each.

QUESTION)

> How do I apply the fill to the interior bounded by the drawn line?

(Also, by the way, in this case, how do I make the decoration arrows larger? Can I apply decoration arrows also the drawn path without breaking the other decoration?)

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}\usepackage{mathtools,tikz,tkz-euclide}\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}\usetkzobj{all}\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}[label]\tkzInit[xmin=-0.8,xmax=10,ymin=-0.4,ymax=8.4] \tkzClip
\tikzset{every node}=[font=\normalsize]

%here_we_make_such_a_dashing
\tikzstyle{finelydashed}=[dash pattern=on 4pt off 7pt]
\tikzstyle{coarselydashed}=[dash pattern=on 7pt off 8pt]

%here_we_make_such_a_shading
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{ltrdiagonals}%
{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{10pt}{10pt}}%
{\pgfqpoint{9pt}{9pt}}{\pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{9.1pt}{9.1pt}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}}%

%here_we_make_such_a_grid
\draw[help lines,color=black!90](0,0)grid(8,8);

%here_we_define_our_several_points
\tkzDefPoint(1,2){v}\tkzDefPoint(7,2){w}  
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center w angle -42](v)
\tkzGetPoint{C}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center v angle 63](w)
\tkzGetPoint{D}
\tkzInterLL(v,D)(C,w)\tkzGetPoint{x}


\tkzDefMidPoint(v,x)\tkzGetPoint{M}

\draw[shade,top color=black!96,bottom color=black!16,fill opacity=0.64,decoration=   {random steps,segment length=22pt,amplitude=11pt},decorate,line width=2pt,rounded corners=8pt](v)--(1.7,3.2)--(4,4)--(6,3)--(w)--(7.4,1)--(0.4,0.4)--(v);
\fill[even odd rule,pattern=ltrdiagonals,pattern color=black!84,decoration={random steps,segment length=24pt,amplitude=0.24cm},decorate,line width=2pt,rounded corners=8pt](v)--(1.7,3.2)--(4,4)--(6,3)--(w)--(7.4,1)--(0.4,0.4)--(v);

%here_we_label_each_node_so
\tkzLabelPoint[above left](v){\LARGE $\boldsymbol{\mathbf{H}_{\;n\;v}}\,$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above left](x){\LARGE $\mathbf{x_{\;n}}$}  
\tkzLabelPoint[right](w){\LARGE $\;\boldsymbol{\mathbf{H}_{\;n\;w}}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.64](v,x,w){\large $\boldsymbol{\varphi}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.64](w,v,x){\large $\boldsymbol{\rho}$}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](M){$\boldsymbol{2\cdot\mu}\;$}

%here_we_construct_each_line_so
\begin{scope}[decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\LARGE\arrow{triangle 45},color=black!96}}]
\draw[-,decorate](v)--(x);
\draw[-,decorate](v)--(w);
\draw[-,decorate](x)--(w);
\end{scope}
\draw[-,line width=1.2pt,coarselydashed,color=black!96](v)--(x);
\draw[-,line width=1.2pt,coarselydashed,color=black!96](v)--(w);
\draw[-,line width=1.2pt,coarselydashed,color=black!96](x)--(w);
\tkzDrawPoints[color=black,shape=circle,fill=black!64,size=16pt](v,x,w)
\tkzMarkAngle[scale=1,line width=1.2pt,finelydashed,color=black!96](v,x,w)
\tkzMarkAngle[scale=1,line width=1.2pt,finelydashed,color=black!96](w,v,x)
\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just asking, but couldn't you just insert `pattern=ltrdiagonals` as a `\draw` option and remove the `\fill`?

Comment: You're right, this works as well!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to reuse the same path with `postaction,preaction` keys.

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,tikz,tkz-euclide}\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[label]
\tkzInit[xmin=-0.8,xmax=10,ymin=-0.4,ymax=8.4] 
\tkzClip
\tikzset{every node}=[font=\normalsize]
%here_we_make_such_a_dashing
\tikzstyle{finelydashed}=[dash pattern=on 4pt off 7pt]
\tikzstyle{coarselydashed}=[dash pattern=on 7pt off 8pt]

%here_we_make_such_a_shading
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{ltrdiagonals}%
{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{10pt}{10pt}}%
{\pgfqpoint{9pt}{9pt}}{\pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{9.1pt}{9.1pt}}%
\pgfusepath{stroke}}%

%here_we_make_such_a_grid
\draw[help lines,color=black!90](0,0)grid(8,8);

%here_we_define_our_several_points
\tkzDefPoint(1,2){v}\tkzDefPoint(7,2){w}  
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center w angle -42](v)
\tkzGetPoint{C}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center v angle 63](w)
\tkzGetPoint{D}
\tkzInterLL(v,D)(C,w)\tkzGetPoint{x}


\tkzDefMidPoint(v,x)\tkzGetPoint{M}

\draw[%shade,
     top color=black!96,
     bottom color=black!16,
     fill opacity=0.64,
     decoration={random steps,segment length=22pt,amplitude=11pt},
     decorate,
     line width=2pt,
     rounded corners=8pt,
     postaction={fill,pattern=ltrdiagonals,pattern color=black!84}
     ](v)--(1.7,3.2)--(4,4)--(6,3)--(w)--(7.4,1)--(0.4,0.4)--(v);


%here_we_label_each_node_so
\tkzLabelPoint[above left](v){\LARGE $\boldsymbol{\mathbf{H}_{\;n\;v}}\,$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above left](x){\LARGE $\mathbf{x_{\;n}}$}  
\tkzLabelPoint[right](w){\LARGE $\;\boldsymbol{\mathbf{H}_{\;n\;w}}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.64](v,x,w){\large $\boldsymbol{\varphi}$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.64](w,v,x){\large $\boldsymbol{\rho}$}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](M){$\boldsymbol{2\cdot\mu}\;$}

%here_we_construct_each_line_so
\begin{scope}[decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\LARGE\arrow{triangle 45},color=black!96}}]
\draw[-,decorate](v)--(x);
\draw[-,decorate](v)--(w);
\draw[-,decorate](x)--(w);
\end{scope}
\draw[-,line width=1.2pt,coarselydashed,color=black!96](v)--(x);
\draw[-,line width=1.2pt,coarselydashed,color=black!96](v)--(w);
\draw[-,line width=1.2pt,coarselydashed,color=black!96](x)--(w);
\tkzDrawPoints[color=black,shape=circle,fill=black!64,size=16pt](v,x,w)
\tkzMarkAngle[scale=1,line width=1.2pt,finelydashed,color=black!96](v,x,w)
\tkzMarkAngle[scale=1,line width=1.2pt,finelydashed,color=black!96](w,v,x)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see `random steps` don't play well with the `rounded corners` option. Also have a look at [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)

Comment: You're right about the tikzset versus style. I forgot about that (I had that question bookmarked already). BTW, *dcmst* suggested putting the pattern in the draw options directly, which also works. Is there a reason to use postaction to bracket the pattern?

Comment: @GuidoJorg dcmst is right but I was not assuming this is the only example. You can do other fill,shade,draw combos that cannot be done at one pass. So take it as an overkill :)

Comment: I've already found it useful for stacking decorations properly. Postaction is very useful. +1