# Draw geometric shape via Latex

Tags: diagrams

Can I draw this shape via LaTeX?

Is there a software to draw any shape as

[image]

Comment: I'm not great in latex, I need a manual or software to draw any mathematical geometry (not the clasical as triangle or ellipse or polygon...)

Comment: Kind of related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35536/586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question smell on "do-it-for-me" questions ...

As starting point, if you like to use `tikz` package for drawing, can serve the following (pseudo)code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1ex]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[draw=green, very thick, rounded corners, fill=gray]
    (<coordinate 1>) -- (<coordinate 2>) -- %and so on
    (<coordinate k>) node[above=3mm] {$\Omega$} -- %and so on
    (<coordinate n) -- cycle;
\draw[draw=red, very thick, rounded corners, fill=white]
    (<coordinate 1>) -- (<coordinate 2>) -- %and so on
    (<coordinate j>) node[above=3mm] {$\Gamma_u$} -- %and so on
    (<coordinate n) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Selection of coordinates is left to you. Also to which one you wish to associate node with $\Gamma_m$.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion code, but isn't running for me

Comment: Of course not. It is not complete. You need to finish it yourself with adding real coordinates, like `(0,0) -- (2,0.5)  -- ` etc. With this and reading TikZ manual or searching for example http://www.texample.net/ you will learn, how to draw similar pictures yourself. Please, edit your question and add it what you try to do with my code and where you stuck