# A sharpy area – a mechanical system

Tags: tikz-pgf

As always I was redrawing a picture with Ti*k*Z. Here is the original:

[image: Screenshot]

Note the “sharpy area“ which is circled in red. I don't know how to achieve this, since I just know how to draw smooth areas. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,calc,intersections,patterns}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,every node/.style={font=\sf\em\tiny}]
        \coordinate (a) at ($(-2.5,.1)+(-1.4,-.7)$);
        \coordinate (b) at ($(2.3,-.35)+(.8,-1.2)$);
        \coordinate (c) at ($(-.2,.3)!.6!(.4,-5.3)$);
        \coordinate (n) at ($(-.2,.3)!.6!(.4,-5.3)$);
        \coordinate (m) at ($(-2.5,.1)!.65!(a)$);
        \coordinate (p) at ($(2.3,-.35)!.65!(b)$);
            \coordinate (c1) at ($(-1,-.5)!.6!(-1.1,-1.4)$);
            \coordinate (c2) at ($(.3,-.45)!.6!(.5,-1.75)$);
            \coordinate (c3) at ($(1.3,-.5)!.6!(1.75,-1.7)$);
            \coordinate (c4) at ($(2.3,-.35)!.6!(3.1,-1.55)$);
                \draw[dashed] ($(-2.5,.1)!.65!(a)$) -- (c) -- ($(2.3,-.35)!.65!(b)$);
                \draw ($(-2.5,.1)!.65!(a)$) -- ($(n)!1.1!(m)$) node[midway,above] {0};
                \draw ($(2.3,-.35)!.65!(b)$) -- ($(n)!1.1!(p)$) node[midway,above] {5};
            \draw (0,0) circle(3 and .9);
                \draw[very thick,->] (-2.5,.1) --+ (-1.4,-.7) node[below right] {$P_1$};
                \draw[very thick,->] (-1,-.5) --+ (-.1,-.9) node[below right] {$P_2$};
                \draw[very thick,->] (.3,-.45) --+ (.2,-1.3) node[below right] {$P_3$};
                \draw[very thick,->] (1.3,-.5) --+ (.45,-1.2) node[below right] {$P_4$};
                \draw[very thick,->] (2.3,-.35) --+ (.8,-1.2) node[right] {$P_5$};
            \draw[fill=white,radius=.1] (-2.5,.1) circle;
            \draw[fill=white,radius=.1] (-1,-.5) circle;
            \draw[fill=white,radius=.1] (.3,-.45) circle;
            \draw[fill=white,radius=.1] (1.3,-.5) circle;
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
                \path[name path=line1] (c3) -- ($(c3)!6.4!(1.3,-.5)$);
                \path[name path=line2] (c4) -- ($(c4)!6.2!(2.3,-.35)$);
                    \path[name intersections={of=line1 and line2, by=nn}];
                        \draw (c3) -- (nn) -- (c4);
                    \fill[pattern=north west lines] (c3) -- ($(2.3,-.35)!.65!(b)$) -- (nn) -- cycle;
            \end{pgfonlayer}
            \draw[fill=white,radius=.1] (2.3,-.35) circle;
                \draw[ultra thick,dashed,->] (-.2,.3) --+ (.6,-5.6) node[above right=3] {\large R$_{1-5}$};
            \draw[very thick,fill=white,radius=.15] (n) circle node[left=7,yshift=-.1cm] {\large $I\!I$};
                \draw ($(-2.5,.1)!.65!(a)$) -- (c1) node[midway,above] {1} -- (c2) node[midway,above=-2] {2} -- (c3) node[midway,above] {3} -- ($(2.3,-.35)!.65!(b)$) node[midway,above,fill=white,inner sep=1.5pt,yshift=.03cm] {4};
                \draw[fill=white,radius=.1] (c1) circle;
                \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
                    \draw (c1) --+ (-1.4,-.4) node[left] {\large $I$};
                \end{pgfonlayer}
            \draw[fill=white,radius=.1] (nn) circle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image: Screenshot_2]

(I left the node “Lageplan u. Seileck“ because it isn't important for the picture.)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Wavy line, but “randomised“](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444276/28808) but no time to check.  See if the decoration applied in the accepted answer there can be applied your case.

Comment: Yes, i checked that but it can't be applied (it's getting too sharpy) …

Comment: I'd expect you to need to fiddle with thte parameters in `random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt},rounded corners=1pt`, for example a lower ratio of amplitude to segment length

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, but that's not still what I want …

Comment: Ahh, the rigid body potato strikes again.

Comment: @joojaa: What do you exactly mean … ?

Comment: Every description of rigid bodies has this representation of a arbitrary body. And because its arbitrary offcourse people choose a shape that signifies arbitrary. A blob, but as my friend pointed out yeah but if its arbitrary your expect somebody to use a drawing of a cylinder or a cone for example. But oh no all material choose to use a ovalish squiggle... that incidentally looks like a potato. Hence potatoes are the go to guys for arbitrary shapes in physics.

Comment: @joojaa: That's the reason why I have decided for the “potato“ … ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can replace

```
\draw (0,0) circle(3 and .9);
```

by

```
\draw[variable=\t,domain=0:360,smooth,samples=60] plot ({cos(\t)*3+0.05*rand},{sin(\t)*0.9+0.05*rand}) -- cycle;
```

You can always play around with the `rand` magnitude a bit. Additionally, changing the number of samples with `samples=<num>` can also change the look for the better. I found that an amplitude of 0.05 works well with `samples=60`.

**Edit**
As mentioned by @marmot in the comments, the `smooth cycle` option ensures that the closing of the cycle is also smooth, and the `tension` can also be reduced. The latest version is produced with:

```
\draw[variable=\t,domain=0:360,smooth cycle,samples=50,tension=0.4] plot ({cos(\t)*3+0.05*rand},{sin(\t)*0.9+0.05*rand});
```

Result:

[image]